# SPARQL - Order By "duplicates"/"rename" property, why?

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, virtuoso

In my Virtuoso (07.00.3203) SPARQL endpoint: http://opendata.caceres.es/sparql

If I make this simple query:

```
select ?uri ?label ?itineraPaso
where {
?uri a om:Procesion.
?uri rdfs:label "Amor el jueves santo."@es .
?uri om:itineraPaso ?itineraPaso.
?itineraPaso rdfs:label ?label.
} order by (?label)
```

I get this output:

[image: img1]

It is like the labels of the different ?itineraPaso were the same (when I know that is not the case).

Then, if I try the same query without the "order by" clause:

```
select ?uri ?label ?itineraPaso
where {
?uri a om:Procesion.
?uri rdfs:label "Amor el jueves santo."@es .
?uri om:itineraPaso ?itineraPaso.
?itineraPaso rdfs:label ?label.
}
```

It works as supposed:
[image]

Do you know why is this happening? How can I order by label elegantly in the same query?

Thanks,

Jesús

EDIT: Sorry, but it seems that images don't work. You can simply click the links.

Comment: Can you show your data, by any chance?  The queries look like they're right, and it could be a Virtuoso bug, but with your data we could actually try to reproduce the behavior.  What version of Virtuoso are you using?

Comment: By the way, what happens if you `order by str(?label)`?

Comment: Pretty sure this is a bug in the SPARQL engine you're using.

Comment: duplicated at http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/31685/order-by-duplicatesrename-property-why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The virtuoso version is: 07.00.3203 .

Funny enough I have tried the same example in an old virtuoso instance we have for testing (ver: 06.01.3127) and it works perfectly, so it must be a bug.

For those who want to replicate the bug, the triples are the following:

https://mega.co.nz/#!QldDySoD!vCnGqlYFCA5-jyMzq3GuRH39Kb2nMiUARG752G1pfAs